# Typescript: как сделать следующий интерфейс?

Tags: typescript

Я хочу реализовать примерно следующий интерфейс, другой вариант предоставлю ниже, но у него есть свой недостаток. Вернее это будет не совсем интерфейс, а тип type

```
type Anything<State extends object = {}> = {
  [key in keyof State]: State[keyof State]
}
```

Это текущий рабочий вариант. Но у него свой минус. Если я передам туда такой интерфейс, то будет работать не совсем корректно

```
interface MyOtherInterface<T> {
  get(): T;
  set(value: T): void;
}

type Anything<State extends object = {}> = {
  [key in keyof State]: MyOtherInterface<State[keyof State]>
};

interface StateStore {
  a: 2;
  b: 3;
  c: 4;
  d: 5;
}

const myOtherFn = <T extends unknown>(value: T) => ({
  get() {
    ...
    return value;
  },
  set(updatedValue: T) {
    ...
  }
});

const store: Anything<StateStore> = {
  a: myOtherFn(3); // or 2, or 5, or 3, or 4
  b: myOtherFn(3); // or 2, or 5, or 3, or 4
  c: myOtherFn(3); // or 2, or 5, or 3, or 4
  d: myOtherFn(3); // or 2, or 5, or 3, or 4
};
```

То есть мы можем передать вообще не то значение, хотя в интерфейсе указано другое, то есть ключ a в store должен быть только 2, но никак не 3, не 4, не 5. А тут все это валидно
Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли сделать что-то следующее:

```
    interface MyOtherInterface<T> {
      get(): T;
      set(value: T): T;
    }

    type Anything<State extends object = {}> = {
      [key in keyof State]: MyOtherInterface<State[key in keyof State]>
    };

    interface StateStore {
      a: 2;
      b: 3;
      c: 4;
      d: 5;
    }
    //Error!
    const store: Anything<StateStore> = {
      a: myOtherFn(3); // Error!
      b: myOtherFn(3); 
      c: myOtherFn(3); 
      d: myOtherFn(3); 
    };

    //or valid

      const store: Anything<StateStore> = {
      a: myOtherFn(2); 
      b: myOtherFn(3); 
      c: myOtherFn(4); 
      d: myOtherFn(5); 
    };
```

Comment: может тебе лучше использовать enum?

Comment: @nörbörnën думаю, он просто упростил до такого вида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> [key in keyof State]: MyOtherInterface<State[keyof State]>
> ```

```
[key in keyof State]: MyOtherInterface<State[key]>
```

Интерфейс целиком:

```
type Anything<State extends object = {}> = {
  [key in keyof State]: MyOtherInterface<State[key]>
};
```

Comment: Да, сработало). Спасибо!

Comment: @Mikhail, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.